# How to convert a NSString to UTF-8 format string in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, utf-8, nsstring

I have localization in my app(english,spanish,italian).The client sent me strings files but some characters are strange how do i correct them? i have figured out that the client used Mac OS Roman encoding how do i convert this to utf-8.
for example Nürnberg
is converted into N√ºrnberg when client send me now i want to reconvert it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a properties file with all of the strings... you can load them in and read them with any of these (from [NSString's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)):

```
– initWithBytes:length:encoding:
– initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:
– initWithCString:encoding:
– initWithUTF8String:
```

Here's the list of all possible encodings

```
enum {
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,                   <----- UTF8!
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
};
```

Answer (score 20):

simple method

```
   [yourNSStringObject UTF8String];
```