# iOS UTF8 Encode

Tags: ios, utf-8

`[myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`
is URL encode. How can I get the real UTF8-Encoding?

Like `myString` is Chinese word `每一天` , and the utf8 string is `&#x6BCF;&#x4E00;&#x5929`

Comment: Do You want to convert String to UTF8-Encoded ????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860277/how-to-convert-a-nsstring-to-utf-8-format-string-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

you should look into [CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH201-F11107) . to encode it to specific language. it will use to convert `CFStringEncoding` to `NSStringEncoding`